# Description text field is not being uploaded to Firestore

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

so here is my jave script which contains my firebase config ive removed my config specification as i uploaded this code here.
the part thats giving me issues is the description text field specifically doesn't upload no matter what. im not sure what to do at this point.
the way the description text field works is fundamentally the same as the other text fields so in theory there should be no issues. i dont believe its an issue with firebase because its just a third text field being uploaded.
i suspect it may be conflicting code but im not sure what to look for.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
api key is there dont worry 
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

const blogTitleField = document.querySelector('.title');
const articleField = document.querySelector('.article');
const DescriptionField = document.querySelector('.description');
// banner
const bannerImage = document.querySelector('#banner-upload');
const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
let bannerPath;

const publishBtn = document.querySelector('.publish-btn');
const uploadInput = document.querySelector('#image-upload');

bannerImage.addEventListener('change', () => {
  uploadImage(bannerImage, "banner");
});

uploadInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  uploadImage(uploadInput, "image");
});

const uploadImage = (uploadFile, uploadType) => {
  const [file] = uploadFile.files;
  if (file && file.type.includes("image")) {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('image', file);

    fetch('/upload', {
      method: 'post',
      body: formdata
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (uploadType === "image") {
        addImage(data, file.name);
      } else {
        bannerPath = `${location.origin}/${data}`;
        banner.style.backgroundImage = `url("${bannerPath}")`;
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please upload an image only.");
  }
};

const addImage = (imagepath, alt) => {
  let curPos = articleField.selectionStart;
  let textToInsert = `\r![${alt}](${imagepath})\r`;
  articleField.value = articleField.value.slice(0, curPos) + textToInsert + articleField.value.slice(curPos);
};

const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

// ...

publishBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  if (articleField.value.length && blogTitleField.value.length) {
    try {
      // Generating ID
      const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      const blogTitle = blogTitleField.value.split(' ').join('-');
      let id = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        id += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
      }

      // Setting up docName
      const docName = `${blogTitle}-${id}`;
      const date = new Date(); // For published at info

      await setDoc(doc(db, 'blogs', docName), {
        description: DescriptionField.value,
        title: blogTitleField.value,
        article: articleField.value,
        bannerImage: bannerPath,
        publishedAt: `${date.getDate()} ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`,
      });

      location.href = `/${docName}`;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   
    <title>blog editor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/editor.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="banner-upload" hidden>
        <label for="banner-upload" class="banner-upload-btn"><img src="img/upload.png" alt="upload banner"></label>
    </div>
   






    <div class="blog">
        <textarea type="text" class="description" placeholder="Start writing here..."></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="title" placeholder="Blog title..."></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="article" placeholder="Start writing here..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-options">
        <button class="btn dark publish-btn">publish</button>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-upload" hidden>
        <label for="image-upload" class="btn grey upload-btn">Upload Image</label>
    </div>

   
<script type="module" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend doing some local debugging yourself. 1. Put a breakpoint on the line `await setDoc(doc(db, 'blogs', docName), {`. 2. Run in the debugger until it stops at the breakpoint. 3. Check the value of `DescriptionField.value`. --- If the value looks correct, but doesn't save: the problem is in the Firestore side of your code. --- If the value is not correct, the problem is in the HTML side of your code.

Comment: none of these solutions worked